# NEXTJS : Button Onclick

Tags: reactjs, next.js

here I have a problem related to the next js project.

**So the case is like this:**

When the "open template" button is pressed, the "choose template" sidebar will appear.

[image]

**But I'm stuck in my coding because when the button is pressed the sidebar on the right doesn't appear.** maybe you guys can help me, i really appreciate your help. Thank you

My Code =

**Template.jsx**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import Image from "next/image";
import styles from "./Template.module.scss";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { FaCheck } from "react-icons/fa";

import { Button } from "../../global/Button";

const Card = ({  data, active, setActive }) => {
    return (
        <div className={styles.card} onClick={() => setActive(data.id)}>
            <Image src={data.image} alt={"template " + data.id} width={116} height={164} />
            {active === data.id && (
                <div className={styles.overlay}>
                    <FaCheck />
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

const Template = ({ list, active, setActive, download }) => {
    const [isResponsive, setResponsive] = useState(typeof window !== "undefined" ? window.innerWidth <= 800 : false);
    const [isHide, setHide] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleResize = () => {
            if (window.innerWidth <= 800) {
                setResponsive(true);
            } else {
                setResponsive(false);
            }
        };

        if (window !== "undefined") window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        setHide(true);
    }, [isResponsive]);

    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <div className={styles.card_container} style={{ right: isHide ? null : 0, position: isResponsive && "relative" }}>
            {isResponsive && !isHide && <div className={styles.template_overlay} onClick={() => setHide(true)} />}
            
            <h3>Pilih Template</h3>
                {list.map((template) => {
                    return <Card data={template} key={template.id} active={active} setActive={setActive} />;
                })}
            </div>
            <Button onClick={download} className={styles.button}>
                DOWNLOAD
            </Button>
        </div>
    );
};

Card.propTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.string,
    active: PropTypes.string,
    setActive: PropTypes.string
};

Template.propTypes = {
    list: PropTypes.string,
    active: PropTypes.string,
    setActive: PropTypes.string,
    download: PropTypes.string,
    isResponsive: PropTypes.bool,
    toggleClick: PropTypes.func,
};

export default Template;
```

**Editor.jsx**

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import styles from "./Editor.module.scss";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Button } from "../../global/Button";

import ColorPicker from "./ColorPicker";

import "react-edit-text/dist/index.css";
import RightArrow from "../../../public/images/qrcode/rightArrow.svg";

let qrCode;
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    console.log("i am client");
    const QRCodeStyling = require("qr-code-styling");
    qrCode = new QRCodeStyling({
        width: 1000,
        height: 1000,
        margin: 50,
        qrOptions: { typeNumber: "0", mode: "Byte", errorCorrectionLevel: "Q" },
        imageOptions: { hideBackgroundDots: true, imageSize: 0.2, margin: 10 },
        dotsOptions: {
            type: "rounded",
            color: "#756ce0",
            gradient: {
                type: "radial",
                rotation: 0,
                colorStops: [
                    { offset: 0, color: "#aa80f9" },
                    { offset: 1, color: "#756ce0" },
                ],
            },
        },
        backgroundOptions: { color: "#ffffff", gradient: null },
        image: "https://i.ibb.co/SrpHzTQ/icon-200px.png",
        dotsOptionsHelper: {
            colorType: { single: true, gradient: false },
            gradient: { linear: true, radial: false, color1: "#6a1a4c", color2: "#6a1a4c", rotation: "0" },
        },
        cornersSquareOptions: { type: "extra-rounded", color: "#756ce0" },
        cornersSquareOptionsHelper: {
            colorType: { single: true, gradient: false },
            gradient: { linear: true, radial: false, color1: "#000000", color2: "#000000", rotation: "0" },
        },
        cornersDotOptions: { type: "", color: "#613583", gradient: null },
        cornersDotOptionsHelper: {
            colorType: { single: true, gradient: false },
            gradient: { linear: true, radial: false, color1: "#000000", color2: "#000000", rotation: "0" },
        },
        backgroundOptionsHelper: {
            colorType: { single: true, gradient: false },
            gradient: { linear: true, radial: false, color1: "#ffffff", color2: "#ffffff", rotation: "0" },
        },
    });
}

import { BsFileEarmarkPdfFill } from "react-icons/bs";
import { IoIosArrowBack } from "react-icons/io";

const Editor = ({ isResponsive, template, list, merchant, setActive, color, toggleClick }) => {
    const { Template } = template;
    const warna = "linear-gradient(180deg, #aa80f9 0%, #756ce0 100%)";
    const router = useRouter();
    const qrRef = useRef();
    const [colorProps, setColorProps] = useState(warna);

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (qrRef.current) qrCode.append(qrRef.current);
        }, 100);
    }, [Template]);

    useEffect(() => {
        qrCode.update({
            data: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SHARE_URL + "/" + router.query.shareKey,
        });
    }, [Template]);

    return (
        <>
            <div className={styles.container}>
                <ColorPicker colorProps={color} callback={(event) => setColorProps(event)} />
                    <Button onClick={toggleClick} className={styles.button}>
                        Open Template
                    </Button>
                    
                <IoIosArrowBack
                    className={styles.arrow + " " + styles.back}
                    onClick={() => {
                        setActive(template.id === 0 ? list.length - 1 : template.id - 1);
                    }}
                />
                <div className={styles.paper_container}>
                    <Template qrRef={qrRef} merchant={merchant} color={colorProps.hex} isResponsive={isResponsive} />
                    <div className={styles.paper_overlay} id="paper-overlay">
                        <BsFileEarmarkPdfFill />
                        <span>Generating PDF</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <RightArrow
                    className={styles.arrow + " " + styles.next}
                    onClick={() => {
                        setActive(template.id === list.length - 1 ? 0 : template.id + 1);
                    }}
                />
            </div>
        </>
    );

Editor.propTypes = {
    template: PropTypes.string,
    list: PropTypes.string,
    merchant: PropTypes.string,
    setActive: PropTypes.string,
    color: PropTypes.string,
    isResponsive: PropTypes.bool,
    toggleClick: PropTypes.func,
};

export default Editor;
```

**[sharekey].jsx**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";
import html2canvas from "html2canvas";
import { serverSideTranslations } from "next-i18next/serverSideTranslations";
import styles from "./Qrcode.module.scss";

import { useRecoilValue } from "recoil";
import { userProfile } from "../../../utils/recoil";

import Sidebar from "../../../components/global/Wrapper/Sidebar/index";
import Editor from "../../../components/edit-survey/qrcode/Editor";
import Template from "../../../components/edit-survey/qrcode/Template";

import TemplateOne from "../../../components/edit-survey/qrcode/template/One";
import TemplateTwo from "../../../components/edit-survey/qrcode/template/Two";
import TemplateThree from "../../../components/edit-survey/qrcode/template/Three";
import TemplateFour from "../../../components/edit-survey/qrcode/template/Four";
import TemplateFive from "../../../components/edit-survey/qrcode/template/Five";
import TemplateSix from "../../../components/edit-survey/qrcode/template/Six";

const Template1 = "/images/qrcode/Template1.jpg";
const Template2 = "/images/qrcode/Template2.jpg";
const Template3 = "/images/qrcode/Template3.jpg";
const Template4 = "/images/qrcode/Template4.jpg";
const Template5 = "/images/qrcode/Template5.jpg";
const Template6 = "/images/qrcode/Template6.jpg";

const templateList = [
    { Template: TemplateOne, id: 0, image: Template1 },
    { Template: TemplateTwo, id: 1, image: Template2 },
    { Template: TemplateThree, id: 2, image: Template3 },
    { Template: TemplateFour, id: 3, image: Template4 },
    { Template: TemplateFive, id: 4, image: Template5 },
    { Template: TemplateSix, id: 5, image: Template6 },
];

const color = {
    r: "170",
    g: "128",
    b: "249",
    a: "1",
};

const Qrcode = () => {
    const [activeTemplate, setActiveTemplate] = useState(0);
    const profile = useRecoilValue(userProfile);

    const [isResponsive, setResponsive] = useState(typeof window !== "undefined" ? window.innerWidth <= 800 : false);
    const [isHide, setHide] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleResize = () => {
            if (window.innerWidth <= 800) {
                setResponsive(true);
            } else {
                setResponsive(false);
            }
        };

        if (window !== "undefined") window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        setHide(true);
    }, [isResponsive]);

    const download = () => {
        const paper = document.getElementById("paper-pdf");
        const overlay = document.getElementById("paper-overlay");

        overlay.style.display = "flex";
        paper.style.transform = "scale(2)";

        html2canvas(paper).then((canvas) => {
            const imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
            const pdf = new jsPDF({
                orientation: "potrait",
                unit: "pt",
                format: "a5",
            });
            const imgProps = pdf.getImageProperties(imgData);
            const pdfWidth = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
            const pdfHeight = (imgProps.height * pdfWidth) / imgProps.width;

            pdf.addImage(imgData, "JPG", 0, 0, pdfWidth, pdfHeight);
            pdf.save("QRCode.pdf");

            paper.style.transform = null;
            overlay.style.display = null;
        });
    };

    return (
        <Sidebar style={{ paddingTop: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0 }}>
            <div className={styles.container}>
                <Editor
                    color={color}
                    template={templateList[activeTemplate]}
                    list={templateList}
                    merchant={profile.merchant}
                    setActive={setActiveTemplate}
                />
                <Template list={templateList} active={activeTemplate} setActive={setActiveTemplate} download={download} toggleClick={() => setHide(!isHide)} />
            </div>
        </Sidebar>
    );
};

export const getServerSideProps = async ({ locale }) => ({
    props: {
        ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale, ["common", "edit-survey"])),
    },
});

export default Qrcode;
```

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox so that we can reproduce so quick?

Answer (score 0):

In your Qrcode.js file You are not passing toggleClick as props to Editor Component..

I think you are mistakenly pass it into template Component

```
             <Editor
                    color={color}
                    template={templateList[activeTemplate]}
                    list={templateList}
                    merchant={profile.merchant}
                    setActive={setActiveTemplate}
                    // toggleClick is missing..
                />
```